# Function to retrieve the size of an element

Tags: c++, position, drag, area

What I need is a function to retrieve the size of an element, be it a Java Applet window in a browser, text boxes in programs, applications window and so on.

Now I don't know what this kind of function is called, but I uploaded an example from an application that had that functionality.

```html
<a href="http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/9638/placementbox.png">Example (The red box)</a>
```

What I need to be able to with this is get its size and its coordinates on the screen. This needs to be in C++.

So ff anyone could give an example, or atleast the name of that kind of function, I would be grateful.

I found a program that has the function I seek: It is called Scar Divi, which is a scriptable tool to perform repetitive actions, mostly uses for cheating in a game called Runescape it seems. Unfortunately it is closed source.

Comment: I uploaded an example of what I seek (while using Scar Divi): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzKxH7H6oMg it is a little speedy, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: There is an oen alternative to SCAR Divi, it is called Simba for more look here: http://wizzup.org/simba/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

```
POINT p;
HWND wnd;
RECT rec;

GetCursorPos(&p);
wnd = WindowFromPoint(p);
GetWindowRect(wnd, &rec);
```

This will give you the coordinates for the box (extract from rec).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [Window Geometry](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/application-windows.html#window-geometry) or [desktop widget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.3/qdesktopwidget.html#details)?

Comment: Neither, uploaded an example on youtube about it, link under the question. It doesn't really have anything to do with Qt after thinking about it. Sorry for the confuse.

Answer (score 0):

After getting an image of the screen (there will be somethign in Qt to do this)

You need an image processing library like [openCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/) to find the rectangle - look for "Hough Transform"

Comment: I believe using OpenCV would be a bit overkill and imprecise for my purpose. I edited my question just before you commented, so you may not have seen it, so sorry for the confuse, but after thinking Qt doesn't really belong to the tags as it really doesn't have anything to do with it. But thanks for your input.

Comment: Do you know that it's red - or was that just an example? Finding all the (possibly overlapping) rectangles on a screen image is a good use for an image processing lib

Comment: The image was just a painted example, the video is a scriptable tool I found that have the function I am seeking. That tool does it without a picture. It works by dragging the cursor over parts of windows and it finds the target area and the coordinates.